# “Epson ET-4750 preparing to print the back side of the document. Do not touch the paper” This is a one-page doc with no back side

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing

This problem began in the last couple of months--one page documents in Microsoft Word and Adobe Acrobat pdfs pause for about 20 seconds after printing the page and the printer Control Panel warns me "Epson ET-4750 preparing to print the back side of the document. Do not touch the paper.” but there is no back side. This long pause before ejecting the printout does not happen when I print one page from SnagIt Editor (a screen shot program). I changed the Universal Print Setting to skip printing of blank pages automatically (p. 64-66 of Epson User Manual) via the Printer Control Panel: Home button, Settings (scroll right on top button bar—last button), General Settings, Printer Settings, Universal Print Settings; Skip Blank Page (scroll down to last button)—ON.

Comment: The text in your answer is rather confused and not formatted in a readable manner.

Comment: Turn off double-sided printing: https://support.epson-europe.com/onlineguides/en/wf7015/html/basic_3.htm